# Google Maps v3 - Zoom-out after event & Info window problems

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My girlfriend says she'll there is a bar of Toblerone for the correct answer... That should tell you that I've been at this one for a few too many hours.

Anyway, I have two issues:

1. Duplicate content within the info windows. Very frustrating. I appreciate this is a duplicate questions (x many) but I'm new to all this and can't for the life of me follow the examples.
2. Google place search works like a charm, however, I'd like to set the zoom to, say, 8 after selecting the location. At the moment the search fires and I'm looking at a rather tight zoom level.

Any help, a fiddle or ANYTHING would be greatly appreciated.

Signed,
Tired & Exasperated

```js
<script>
 var map;
 function initialize() {
     var markers = [];
     var mapOptions = {
         zoom: 4,
         scrollwheel: false,
        streetViewControl: true,
        panControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
        },

         center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.898854, 134.091377),
     };
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
     mapOptions);

     setMarkers(map, beaches);

     infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
         content: "Loading..."
     });

     var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
         document.getElementById('pac-input'));
         map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

     var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
         /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));

     google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
            marker.setMap(null);
     }

     markers = [];
     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
     for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {

     var image = {
         //url: 'assets/img/icon_pin.png',
         //size: new google.maps.Size(40, 52),
         //origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
         //anchor: new google.maps.Point(26, 20)
     };

     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         icon: image,
         title: place.name,
         position: place.geometry.location

     });

     markers.push(marker);
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
     }

     map.fitBounds(bounds);
 });

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {       
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
        searchBox.setBounds(bounds);

        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    });
 }

 var beaches = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

 function setMarkers(map, locations) {
     var image = {
         url: 'assets/img/icon_pin.png',
         size: new google.maps.Size(40, 52),
         origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
         anchor: new google.maps.Point(26, 20)
     };

     var shape = {
         coord: [1, 1, 1, 52, 40, 52, 40 , 1],
         type: 'poly'
     };
     for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
         var beach = locations[i];
         var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: myLatLng,
             map: map,
             icon: image,
             shape: shape
         });

        var contentString = '<div class="siteNotice"><h4>'+beach[0]+'</h4></div>';                

         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
             infowindow.setContent(contentString);
             infowindow.open(map, this);
         });
     }
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Question 1) what do you want to duplicate? Need more info.

Comment: MrUpsidown - Sorry if I was unclear. The issue is that ALL info windows contain duplicate content. The content is the final line in the 'beaches' array ('Maroubra Beach'). I'd like each info window to have it's own information.

Comment: Question 2) add a `map.setZoom(8)` at the end of your `places_changed` event should do the trick.

Comment: Can you try to create a fiddle with working code? I can see a few issues and many errors in my console with the above code.

Comment: Q1: duplicate of xy - put `(function(contentString){` and `})(contentString);` around `click` event listener in `setMarker()`.

Comment: MrUpsidown/Anto - Thank you for your help. Both issues now resolved. I can't tell you how grateful I am.

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
> var map;
>         function initialize() {
>             var markers = [];
>             var mapOptions = {
>                 zoom: 4,
>                 scrollwheel: false,
>               streetViewControl: true,
>               panControl: true,
>               zoomControl: true,
>               zoomControlOptions: {
>                   style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
>               },
> 
>                 center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.898854, 134.091377),
>             };
>             map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
>             mapOptions);
>             
>             setMarkers(map, beaches);
>     
>             infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
>                 content: "Loading..."
>             });
>             
>             var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
>                 document.getElementById('pac-input'));
>                 map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
>             
>             var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
>                 /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));
>     
>             google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
>               var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
>               
>               for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
>                   marker.setMap(null);
>                   
>                   map.setZoom(8)
>               }
>     
>               markers = [];
>               var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
>               for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
>   
>               var image = {
>                   //url: 'assets/img/icon_pin.png',
>                   //size: new google.maps.Size(40, 52),
>                   //origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
>                   //anchor: new google.maps.Point(26, 20)
>               };
>       
>               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
>                   map: map,
>                   icon: image,
>                   title: place.name,
>                   position: place.geometry.location
>   
>               });
>       
>               markers.push(marker);
>                   bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
>               }
>     
>               map.fitBounds(bounds);
>               
>               map.setZoom(11)
>           });
> 
>       google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {       
>           var bounds = map.getBounds();
>               searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
>               
>               map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());            });
>         }
>     
>        var beaches = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
  ];
>     
>         function setMarkers(map, locations) {
>             var image = {
>                 url: 'assets/img/icon_pin.png',
>                 size: new google.maps.Size(40, 52),
>                 origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
>                 anchor: new google.maps.Point(26, 20)
>             };
>       
>             var shape = {
>                 coord: [1, 1, 1, 52, 40, 52, 40 , 1],
>                 type: 'poly'
>             };
>             for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
>                 var beach = locations[i];
>                 var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
>                 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
>                     position: myLatLng,
>                     map: map,
>                     icon: image,
>                     shape: shape
>                 });
>             
>           
>               
>               var contentString = '<div class="siteNotice"><h4>'+beach[0]+'</h4></div>';                
>               (function(contentString){
>                 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
>                     infowindow.setContent(contentString);
>                     infowindow.open(map, this);
>                 });
>               
>               })(contentString);
>             }
>         }
>         google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```